# Validate boolean true

Tags: java, tapestry

I have a boolean inside a Checkbox and i want to validate if it is set to True.

So my entitie object looks kind of like this

```
@Validate("required,min=1")
private int Int1;
```

In my tml File (im using Tapestry 5.3.8) there is a Textfield which allows me to set a value for Int1

this works perfectly. If i put something else then an numeric number (or an int small 1) it shows me an error dialog.

but i can't figure out how to do that with a boolean. It needs to be checked an the user should get the same behauvior as with Int1 on a false entry.

Think of it like an Agree to the TOS checkbox which allways has to be checked to proceed.

Greetings Ilja

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken a checkbox works with a boolean. So the following should achieve your result:

```
@Component(id = "agreeCheckbox")
private Checkbox agreeCheckbox;

@OnEvent(component = "agreeCheckbox", value = EventConstants.VALIDATE)
private void handleAgreeValidate(boolean agree) {
  if(!agree) {
    throw new ValidationException("Hey there! You have to agree or we can't do business with you.");
  }
}
```

**Disclaimer:** I have not tested this code.